# How to record sound on internal recording

Tags: android, record

I know how to record and save to file on my app
But how can i record sound from my device media player to my app at real time recording.
that means: when i hear song on my device and when i click "record" it will recording the sound to a new file (No using the microphon to record) just internal Recording.
any suggestions or tips?

Comment: If you mean being able to record the audio output of other applications, then the answer is that it isn't supported (I'm not counting the `Visualizer` API, because the quality of the audio you get from it is too low for most purposes other than visualization).

Comment: But I saw an app very similar to my description. that do all i asked